# Woocommerce API request returns few products

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have tried to retrieve all the products of a Woocommerce shop using this kind of request, but I only get 10 products:

```
http://www.mystore.com/wc-api/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_1234&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1488898708&oauth_nonce=a83kF3&oauth_signature=whatever
```

The only solution I found is to add a filter in the request in order to get a specific number of products, ex: `&filter[limit]=1000`. This works fine but the problem is that I need a generic solution because now I want to get products from multiple stores and some of them can have thousands of products.

Is there a better way to get all the products of a store without setting the limit?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that -1 is doing the job: `&filter[limit]=-1` or `filter%5Blimit%5D=-1`

I will add a hint in case someone ends up in the same situation...

if you need to make an API call using Java, make sure you encrypt the above filter together with the rest authorization parameters so as to get the oauth signature.